# When I must use the "throws" word in declaration of a method?

Tags: java, javacard

I know it is simple, but as a newbie in java, I have problem with it!

This is a simple Java Card applet that returns SW=`0xEE 0xFF` on reception of any command :

```
package secondStep; 
import javacard.framework.*;

public class BadRepeater extends Applet
{
    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength) throws ISOException 
    {
        new BadRepeater().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU arg0) throws ISOException 
    {
        ISOException.throwIt((short)0xeeff);
    }  
}
```

I remove the words `throws ISOException` from the end of `process` method declaration line :

```
package secondStep; 
import javacard.framework.*;

public class BadRepeater extends Applet
{
    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength) throws ISOException 
    {
        new BadRepeater().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU arg0) 
    {
        ISOException.throwIt((short)0xeeff);
    }  
}
```

Both of the above programs works fine.

The question is "what is the difference?"

When I must use the word `throws ...` at the end of the line and when I don't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must declare checked exceptions only. You may declare unchecked exceptions, to indicate they are likely to be thrown.

For example `parseInt(String s)` declares it throws a `NumberFormatException`, even though it is unchecked, because it is likely to do it (passing it not a number is a common scenario).

From the docs (emphasis mine):

> Runtime exceptions can occur anywhere in a program, and in a typical one they can be very numerous. Having to add runtime exceptions in every method declaration would reduce a program's clarity. Thus, the compiler does not require that you catch or specify runtime exceptions (**although you can**).

### The Exception Heirarchy

[image: The Exception Heirarchy]

Whether an exception is checked or unchecked depends on what it extends / implements.

The root of all unexpected events is the `Throwable` interface. There are two types of `Throwable`, `Error` and `Exception`.

`Error` is used for fatal JVM events, such as `ThreadDeath`. It's very rare that you'll want to handle these events, so they are split off.

`Exception` is the root type for all exceptions, checked and un-checked. An exception that extends `Exception` and not `RuntimeException` will be checked.

`RuntimeException` extends `Exception` and allows it to be unchecked.

`ISOException` is unchecked and therefore extends `RuntimeException` (or it's parent/grandparent/etc does). In this case, it extends `CardRuntimeException` which extends `RuntimeException` ([based on the Javadoc I found](http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/apis/jc222/javacard/framework/ISOException.html))

Comment: Thank you. May I ask you to add a little explanation that "what is the difference between checked exceptions and unchecked ones?" ,please. In the other word, what makes an exception checked?

Answer (score 2):

You must use `throw` when both conditions below are true:

- The declared exception is *not* derived from `RuntimeException`,
- There is a code path in your method that `throw`s that exception, or calls a method with this exception in the `throws` declaration.

`ISOException` does not meet the first criterion, because it derives from `RuntimeException`. Hence, its declaration is optional.

Note that adding `throws` is a breaking change, because the code that calls your method needs to catch your exception. That is why you are allowed to add `throws` for an exception that you never actually `throw`, so that you could add a `throw` for it later.

Comment: ISOException is a runtimeexception, hence it is an unchecked exception. http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/apis/jc222/javacard/framework/ISOException.html To learn more about 

Checked vs Unchecked Exceptions in Java
 http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/checked-vs-unchecked-exceptions-in-java/

Answer (score 1):

ISOException is a subclass of RuntimeException, so it's not a checked exception and therefore doesn't need a throws clause.

Answer (score 1):

you only must include a "throws" clause on a method if the exception it throws is a checked exception. If the method throws a runtime exception, is optional. In this case, as [ISOException is a runtime exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/opt-pkgs/api/security/satsa-api/jsr177/javacard/framework/ISOException.html), both programs work fine.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

General consensus seems to be that you should document an exception in the JavaDoc of a method when you *expect* to throw it. This is even true for  `RuntimeException`s. You can document them using `@throws`.

In JavaCard many exceptions also take a `reason` (a short). In those cases you should clearly indicate which reason codes can be generated (using a list, with tags `<ul>` or `<ol>` in HTML and a `<li>` for each item). For `ISOException` instances the reason code will be translated into a ISO 7816 status word (at the end of the `process` method, if the exception is not caught). In the case of status words you may even want to specify the *order* in which the status words can occur.

Runtime exceptions are generally not part of the method signature, so - again by general consensus - you should *not* declare them using `throws` within the method signature. Checked exceptions of course *have* to be put in the method signature.

Basically all JavaCard exceptions (except `UserException`) are runtime exceptions, so the part about checked exceptions may be safely ignored. For a good example of how to describe exceptions take a look at the Java Card API.